# API Gateway Design

Tags: architecture, microservices, api-gateway

Api gateway http://microservices.io/patterns/apigateway.html seems to be a good pattern to be adopted in Micro Service architecture(Not internal communication between services).

But I have below queries

1. I am unable to understand how API Gateways should be designed itself. We can't have just one api gateway for all services. For example for Uber we have 
   **Trip, Cabs, Driver, User, Pricing** Micro Services, so how many API Gateways should we design.
2. In  https://medium.com/netflix-techblog/optimizing-the-netflix-api-5c9ac715cf19 what does Dynamic Endpoints means.

I was thinking like in Uber case,to display user first page we will need cabs and pricing. So we will expose an API in api-gateway some /home and from here asynchronously we will call Pricing and Cabs api will merge and return the response. Is there any batter way to do this?

Comment: Did the answer below helped you?

Answer (score 1):

In a cloud architecture, when you have a RESTful interface, you usually have one API Gateway redirecting your requests to a load balancer, serverless function, queue or whatever you want/need: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started.html

For communication between microservices, I would suggest a messaging queue for decoupling purposes. Your merge idea could become hard to maintain after some time. Check out SQS: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-tutorials.html